# Is there a way to set the cell content and imagaView from didSelectRowAtIndexPath?

Tags: ios

Is there a way to set the cell content and imagaView from:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

?

I want to update the cell when it is selected, before to update the tabledataSource.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could get a reference to your cell like this...

```
UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [self cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Then do modifications like...

```
selectedCell.titleLabel.text = @"new title";
selectedCell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"newImage.png"];
```

Comment: Also you may need to update this cell with call `[selectedCell setNeedsDisplay]`

Comment: I don't think you need to call setNeedsDisplay. Above should be sufficient,